# "Solids have distinct boundaries" meaning

Tags: matter, states-of-matter

That may sound very silly questions but believe me I'm unable to understand that .

I'm unable to visualise how solid can be said to have distinct boundaries . Please help me so I can make the picture of it in my mind .

If I'm missing something related to question please let me known. Thank you!!

Comment: When you visualize a solid, do you visualize something that *doesn't* have boundaries?

Comment: @d_b I visualise things like a cube, baseball bat, needle etc

Comment: @d_b so I find what boundary of baseball bat would be or a sphere solid like ball

Comment: Do you know what a [boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)) is?

Comment: @Sandejo what I know , boundaries is  all points on it's surface

Comment: Right, and a baseball bat has a very obvious boundary / surface. Do you disagree?

Comment: @d_b ok baseball bat has distinct boundaries from its surroundings and other things but then this is same for water also in liquid form i.e distinct boundaries from other things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gasses and liquids can assume different shapes, they have no set form. However a solid has a definite shape with distinct edges (boundaries).

Comment: But sir  there's no edge in a solid sphere

Comment: But a sphere has a boundary. It is bounded by all points that are a certain distance (radius) from it's centre. Do you agree with that?

Answer (score 0):

A solid is a state of matter that retains its shape and density when not confined. The outline of the shape is the boundary and the boundary is distinct because it retains its shape.